# Writing a connection string

Tags: sql-server

I am willing to write a connection string to allow one computer connect to another computer's sql server located in the same work group.
Anyway, searching the Internet only confused me and led me to fail tries.

So, if I am willing to connect to an sql express server to a database called "Analyze", what should my connection string look like?

Comment: This page should give you everything you need to know https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new text file with the extension UDL in a folder.

Right click on the file and click open with "OLE DB Core Services"
Filll in the appropriate entries and save.

Open the file in notepad - voila, your connection string is in there.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx) explaining how to connect to SQL Server express over a network.

The main points are; you need to configure SQL Server to listen for requests.  This can be done using the SQL Browser.  You also need to ensure the firewall will allow requests through.